# Photo not visible for my friends but it's on my timeline

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

From my app I can send the photos and it's updated on the timeline but none of my friend get to see it. I tried the secret code of other sample apps on my app plist and tried sending the photo. It works charm. Could anyone tell what could be wrong with the FB secret pin? I gave permission as Extended Permissions: publish_stream photo_upload

```
[self performPublishAction:^{

        [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:image
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                                   if (!error) {
                                       textView.text = result[@"id"];
                                       NSLog(@"Posted : %@", result);
                                       post_Photo.enabled = TRUE;

                                   }
                                   else
                                       NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
                               }];

    }];

- (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {

    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] == NSNotFound) {


        [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream"]
                                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                if (!error) {
                                                    action();
                                                }
                                                //For this example, ignore errors (such as if user cancels).
                                            }];
    } else {
        action();
    }

}
```

Comment: put your Trying code with Question.

Comment: have you try using FriendPickerViewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL. I didn't change the app settings from Sandboxing enabled to disabled, so it was only available for development team.